# Solve these simple simultaneous equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assuming $x_1, x_2 \geq 0, \lambda \neq 0, w_1,w_2 > 0$

We have the equalities:

$$w_1 - \lambda x_2 = 0 ... (1)$$
$$w_2 - \lambda x_1 = 0 ... (2)$$
$$\bar y - x_1x_2= 0 ... (3)$$

My solutions say that $\lambda^* = \sqrt\frac{w_1w_2}{\bar y}$
Which I was able to solve myself.

The other solution is $x^* = (\frac{w_2 \bar y}{w_1}, \frac{w_1 \bar y}{w_2})$

Which I cannot seem to get. Would anyone be so kind as to point out how to obtain solutions for $x^*$ ?

I tried:

$x_1= \frac{w_2}{\lambda}$ and $x_2 = \frac{w_1}{\lambda}$

then put these into the 3rd equation, but ended up gettig
$\bar y = \frac{w_1w_2}{\lambda^2}$ which I couldn't see turning into what I needed either way(even just subbing in one of the x-values at a time.

Comment: If you plug the second solution into the third equation you get y-y^2=0. If y=0 you get that the w's are 0, so this implies y=1. Then the first two equations imply w1=w2=1, so everything is 1, which is indeed a solution.

Comment: Where are you getting $y-y^2=0$ from ?

plugging $(2)$ into $(3)$ leaves me with $\bar y - \frac{w_2x_2}{\lambda} = 0$

Comment: If $x_1 = \frac{w_2 y}{w_1}$ and $x_2 = \frac{w_1 y}{w_2}$ then $x_1 x_2 = y^2$, no?

Comment: Am I missing something? I Can't see how you obtained $x_1 = \frac{w_2y}{w_1}$ or $x_2 = ...$

Individually they are $x_1 = \frac{w_2}{\lambda}$ and $x_2 = \frac{w_1}{\lambda}$

How can I get the solution for $x^*$ ?

Comment: I was just mentioning that the second solution you present implies that all of the variables are equal to 1.

Comment: @ZurLuria Ah right. No I see that as well, I'm just unsure what manipulations are required to obtains $x^*$. Could you help me with that?